# Hover every div but one that' hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to make after hover module-wrap div to set opacity on other on 0.3 and show only hovered `div`. I make something like that in my css:

I have something like that:

```css
.wrap:hover .module-wrap:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.wrap:hover>*:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="module-wrap">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
  <div class="module-wrap">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
  <div class="module-wrap">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
  <div class="module-wrap">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works - when I hover on one element, other are set to `opacity: 0.3`. But when I hover over wrap it makes everything set opacity 0.3. I just want to set it on divs and when I hover other place in wrap than div, to make it opacity 1. How can I do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/69n8y4hb/3/

Comment: I added jsfiddle

Comment: This cannot be done only with css. You have to add JavaScript to do this.

Comment: Can please help me with that? I'm stuck :( how this code should look like?

Comment: Okay I will send you complete solution in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this (with JQuery):

```
$('.module-wrap').hover(
  function() {
    $('.module-wrap').css('opacity', '0.3')
    $(this).css('opacity', '1')
  }, function() {
    $('.module-wrap').css('opacity', '1');
  }
)
```

Comment: Let me know if you need further explanation what this code does :)

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome :) You can mark my answer as the solution to your question. Future guests here will find this solution faster then.